# setFile() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, string given

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, silex

I'm working with doctrine and forms on a silex project. I have created a file formfield but when i select a file and submit the form the next error is given.

Argument 1 passed to models\Page::setFile() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, string given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/admin/vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessor.php on line 410 and defined

The `$request->files` are also empty and the error is given when i call the `$form->handleRequest($request)` function.

formbuilder Pagetype.php

```
<?php
namespace forms\type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PageType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->id = $options['data']->id;
    if($this->id == null){$this->id = 0;}
    $builder
        ->add('title', 'text', array('attr' => array('class'=>'form-control')))
        ->add('slug', 'text', array('required' => false,
                'attr' => array('class'=>'form-control')
            ))
        ->add('intro', 'textarea')
        ->add('text', 'textarea')
        ->add('file', 'file', array("required" => false,
                                "file_path" => UPLOAD_DIR,
                                "file_name" => "path",))

        ->add('tags', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new TagType(), 
                'options' => array('label' => false, 'attr'=>array('class'=>'form_collection_item clearfix')), 
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'attr'=>array('class'=>'form_collection clearfix')
            ))
        ->add('subpage', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'models\Page',
                'required' => false,
                'property' => 'title',
                'placeholder' => '-- Main Page --',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {

                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                            ->where('p.view_status != -1 and p.id != '.$this->id.'');
                    },
                'attr' => array('class'=>'form-control')
            ))
        ->add('view_status', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(5 => 'Actief', 2 => 'Niet Actief'),
                'expanded' => false,
                'attr' => array('class'=>'form-control')
            ))
    ;


}

public function getName()
{
    return 'page';
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'models\Page',
    ));
}
}
```

model Page.php

```
<?php

namespace models;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
* @Entity @Table(name="pages")
**/
class Page
{
/** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
public $id;

/** @Column(type="string", nullable=false) **/
public $title;

/** @Column(type="string", nullable=true) **/
public $slug;

/** @Column(type="text", nullable=true) **/
public $intro;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
private $file;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page")
 * @JoinColumn(name="subpage_of", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
public $subpage;

/** @Column(type="text", nullable=true) **/
public $text;

/** @Column(type="integer", nullable=false) **/
public $view_status;

/** @Column(type="datetime", nullable=true) **/
protected $pub_date;

/** @Column(type="datetime", nullable=true) **/
public $chg_date;

/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="models\Tag", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $tags;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
public $path;

public function __toString()
{
    return (string) $this->getTitle();
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function upload()
{
    die();
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // use the original file name here but you should
    // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

    // move takes the target directory and then the
    // target filename to move to
    $this->getFile()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName()
    );

    // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->path = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->file = null;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/documents';
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file.
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set slug
 *
 * @param string $slug
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setSlug($slug)
{
    $this->slug = $slug;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get slug
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSlug()
{
    return $this->slug;
}

/**
 * Set intro
 *
 * @param string $intro
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setIntro($intro)
{
    $this->intro = $intro;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get intro
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getIntro()
{
    return $this->intro;
}

/**
 * Set photo
 *
 * @param string $photo
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setPhoto($photo)
{
    $this->photo = $photo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get photo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhoto()
{
    return $this->photo;
}

/**
 * Set text
 *
 * @param string $text
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setText($text)
{
    $this->text = $text;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get text
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getText()
{
    return $this->text;
}

/**
 * Set viewStatus
 *
 * @param integer $viewStatus
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setViewStatus($viewStatus)
{
    $this->view_status = $viewStatus;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get viewStatus
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getViewStatus()
{
    return $this->view_status;
}

/**
 * Set pubDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $pubDate
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setPubDate($pubDate)
{
    $this->pub_date = $pubDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get pubDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getPubDate()
{
    return $this->pub_date;
}

/**
 * Set chgDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $chgDate
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setChgDate($chgDate)
{
    $this->chg_date = $chgDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get chgDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getChgDate()
{
    return $this->chg_date;
}

/**
 * Set subpage
 *
 * @param \models\Page $subpage
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setSubpage(\models\Page $subpage = null)
{
    $this->subpage = $subpage;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get subpage
 *
 * @return \models\Page
 */
public function getSubpage()
{
    return $this->subpage;
}

/**
 * Add tag
 *
 * @param \models\Tag $tag
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function addTag(\models\Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tag;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove tag
 *
 * @param \models\Tag $tag
 */
public function removeTag(\models\Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}

/**
 * Set path
 *
 * @param string $path
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setPath($path)
{
    $this->path = $path;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get path
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
}
}
```

values after submit

```
    object(stdClass)#327 (13) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(11) "models\Page"
  ["id"]=>
  int(66)
  ["title"]=>
  string(4) "mama"
  ["slug"]=>
  NULL
  ["intro"]=>
  NULL
  ["file"]=>
  NULL
  ["subpage"]=>
  object(stdClass)#493 (15) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(11) "models\Page"
    ["__IS_PROXY__"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["__PROXY_INITIALIZED__"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["id"]=>
    int(65)
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "hans"
    ["slug"]=>
    NULL
    ["intro"]=>
    NULL
    ["file"]=>
    NULL
    ["subpage"]=>
    NULL
    ["text"]=>
    NULL
    ["view_status"]=>
    int(5)
    ["pub_date"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["chg_date"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["tags"]=>
    string(8) "Array(0)"
    ["path"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["text"]=>
  NULL
  ["view_status"]=>
  int(5)
  ["pub_date"]=>
  object(stdClass)#575 (3) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["date"]=>
    string(25) "2015-07-31T16:17:44+02:00"
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  ["chg_date"]=>
  object(stdClass)#557 (3) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["date"]=>
    string(25) "2015-07-31T16:27:39+02:00"
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  ["tags"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "models\Tag"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "models\Tag"
  }
  ["path"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Comment: Just to make sure, post the results of a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` from your controller, before calling the $form->handleRequest().

Comment: There are no `file_path` and `file_name` options in the standard `File` form type. Are you using custom form type?

Comment: It seems like the file input doesn't work. I still don't know how to fix this

Comment: @lazypanda does your form renders with `enctype='multipart/form-data'` support or not ? reference http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid not by calling the form rendering function. Or do you mean I have to put it there myself?

Comment: @lazypanda to send files to server your opening form tag should have this attribute and your request method should be post

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error message and found that the form did not have enctype='multipart/form-data'.

By adding this to the form tag, the problem was resolved.